# Strange Email After Sending Contact Form

Tags: php, forms, email, contacts

Every time someone fills out my contact form, it sends a strange email.

The email subject is "Undelivered Mail Returned to Sender"

The error of the email is here: https://hastebin.com/lihikuzubi.http

The PHP code that sends the email is found here: https://hastebin.com/ivibojisis.pl

Also, how do I make it so it opens a bootstrap modal when the email successfully sends.

Comment: Could you show us the code what does send the email?

Comment: Yeah sure. Added it on a HasteBin as well as the Error Message to clean this up a bit and easier to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This mail server **mail-out.ovh.net** is bouncing the email back because their script `/localscripts/hosting-mailout/ovh-mailtrap.py` has issues. I am not sure if that is your smtp server or not. But the problem is with the python script and the errors (2) that it is having.

**UPDATED**
The mail server is running a script during the processing of the email that it receives. This python script is throwing an error which causes the mail server to bounce the email back to the sender. This is why you are getting the email back with this information. This question really has nothing to do with the PHP and sending the email since the email is sent and now the problem is with the mail server.

Comment: Ah. How can I fix this issue then?

Comment: If it is your mail server, you will have to fix the python script. If it is not your mail server, then there is nothing that you can do but talk to the owner of the mail server and have them fix it.

Comment: Alright. Thanks for your answer. I've contacted my host and hopefully they can fix it.